# How to Use gobuffalo/packr with Golang

Tags: go

I'm trying to play a sound from Golang.  It's a .wav file.  And I want to package the .wav file into the executable using [packr](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr)

I have created a very small project here: [packr-test repository](https://github.com/Davo36/packr-test) with the code.

When I run the executable (./packr-test) in it's default folder, the sound plays. 
 But the problem I'm having is that when I move the executable to another directory, I get an error trying to play the sound file.  Which I think probably means the sound file isn't being bundled up with the executable.

This is on Ubuntu.  I'm using the 'play' command which is often installed by default, but if it's not there, can be done with:

```
sudo apt-get install sox
sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
```

To use play command:

```
play file_name.extension
```

To save you looking it up, here is my Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"

    "github.com/gobuffalo/packr"
)

func main() {

    soundsBox := packr.NewBox("./sounds")
    if soundsBox.Has("IEEE_float_mono_32kHz.wav") {
        fmt.Println("It's there.")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("It's not there.")
    }

    args := []string{"-v20", "./sounds/IEEE_float_mono_32kHz.wav"}
    output, err := exec.Command("play", args...).Output()
    if err != nil {
        // Play command was not successful
        fmt.Println("Got an error.")
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(output))
    }

}
```

Here is my output:

```
sudo ./packr-test 
It's there.
Got an error.
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're still referencing the file on the file system, even though you have it packed into the binary:

```
args := []string{"-v20", "./sounds/IEEE_float_mono_32kHz.wav"}
output, err := exec.Command("play", args...).Output()
```

You can grab the file data from your packr box like this:

```
bytes, err := soundsBox.FindBytes("IEEE_float_mono_32kHz.wav")
```

To execute the file with `exec.Command()` I think you'll have to write those bytes back to the file system:

```
err := ioutil.WriteFile("/tmp/IEEE_float_mono_32kHz.wav", bytes, 0755)
exec.Command("play", []string{"-v20", "/tmp/IEEE_float_mono_32kHz.wav"}
```

You might be able to pass your bytes to `play` via stdin, but that would depend on how the `play` binary works.

```
cmd.Stdin = bytes
cmd.Run()
```

Comment: Hmmm, this seems right.  But then wouldn't every resource packed into a binary with packr suffer from the same problem?  Like say you pack some html files, then serve them up, why don't they need to be re-written back out to the file system?

Comment: It depends how you use the file data. I use packr a lot to embed things like SQL queries, HTML templates, images, fonts, etc but I read the bytes from the packr box and then pass those bytes directly to a function that accepts a `[]byte` parameter. You're calling `exec` which is an operating system call so you have pass your sound file the same way you would if you called `play` on the command line (i.e. as a file system path).

Comment: Yes I see what you mean.  I think you're probably right. Bugger.  This means we may as well distribute the sound files with the executable.  Either that or try and find some way of playing the files without calling exec...

Comment: I had a quick look at some Go audio libraries, there's a few around, but I'm not sure how nice they are to use. Here's an [mp3 one](https://github.com/hajimehoshi/go-mp3) for example.